# Is more than one deck of cards ever used in Phase 10?

Tags: phase-10

When 4-6 players are playing Phase 10 is it possible that the deck can be exhausted before anyone completes a phase?

Comment: It's been many years since I played, but yes, we have had an instance where we made it through the draw pile without anyone going out.  (There were 5 of us).  We used to play a lot, so I think it's rare.  We just took the discard pile (except the top card) and shuffled it to make a new draw pile.

Comment: @AdamKlump Write this as an answer.

Comment: Okay.  I felt since this was not in the rules, I just assumed how we handled it in house, would be seen as a house rule and not an answer.  But I'll move it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have had an instance where we made it through the draw pile without anyone going out. (There were 5 of us). We used to play a lot, so I think it's rare. We just took the discard pile (except the top card) and shuffled it to make a new draw pile.  I didn't see this situation in the rules though, so it's unofficial.